# Обновление атрибута сессии в jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

При первом открытии страницы я устанавливаю атрибут сессии

```
 request.getSession().removeAttribute("currentCity");
 request.getSession().setAttribute("currentCity", cityName);
```

и в jsp он отображается правильно, но когда я пытаюсь изменить его(этим же кодом), то в jsp он все равно отображает тот, который я установил в 1 раз. В jsp сессии включены 
`<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"  session="true" %>`

Пробовал доставать его по разному, результат всегда один и тот же.

```
${sessionScope.currentCity}

<%
System.out.println(session.getAttribute("currentCity"));
System.out.println(request.getAttribute("currentCity"));
System.out.println(request.getSession().getAttribute("currentCity"));
System.out.println(pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("currentCity"));
System.out.println(pageContext.getAttribute("currentCity"));
%>
```

При этом `session` в `request` null, а в `pageContext` нет. И установленное значение хранится именно в `pageContext -> session`. Возможно, я неправильно устанавливаю значение?

Как его изменить, чтобы на странице отображался актуальный? Или как его правильно доставать?

Comment: В дебаге смотрели что устанавливается в сессию?

Comment: Конечно. Устанавливается то, что нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Проблему решил, добавив контроллеру аннотации

```
@Scope("session")
@SessionAttributes("currentCity")
```

И передав объект в модель.

```
public ModelAndView ev(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("cityEvent");
    String currentCity = "name";
    mav.addObject("currentCity", currentCity);
    return mav;
}
```